# How to track events in extension?

Tags: ios8, apple-watch

Most iOS analytics tools (flurry, new relics) use the standard uiapplication delegate methods to upload events in batch, every minute or when the application terminate. I haven't seen any dedicated solution for extension (today, photo...) from these guys. What do you do for analytics in extension in ios8?

Comment: How did you work around this? I'm interested as well.

Comment: Still can't find a good tool for tracking extensions.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I used two work arounds
1 - I used app group shared data https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html and I log the event when the user open the containing app
2 - My today extension allow user to openURL to open the containing app, I pass data in the params of the url.

Comment: According to dev evangelists in the dev forums, openURL will not work from an extension.

Comment: @bgilham openURL is not supposed to work for "share extension" or "action extension" but totally fine for "today extension" (most today extension use this)

Answer (score 3):

In my WatchKit app, I use `openParentApplication:reply:` to pass a request to the host app and log my analytics from there.

Comment: Intersting, it seems to only work for the watch extension though

Comment: I think this is actually the better solution! It's a pain to have to rig this way, but seems more pure to me than sharing data!

Answer (score 0):

Flurry has announced support for Apple Watch extensions. You can find out more in the developer documentation here:
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/technicalquickstart/applewatch/

It's possible that this will open the door for tracking activity within other extensions, but I haven't seen anything about it yet.

Comment: I did check it - Flurry work with the watch but do NOT work with extensions like the custom keyboard. BTW I like it